# Get files from TFS Source Control added by another developer without checking in my code first?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I'm working with Wally, another developer on the Acorn project. (both names ficticious)

The Acorn project is an ASP.net Web Project; the source code is in TFS (Team Foundation Server).  Wally tells me that he checked in new code yesterday, as I expected.  I sit down and run the merge tool and take notes of the places where we've worked on the same file.  I used the Visual Studio Merge Tool to merge and then proceeded to test the code.

It didn't work.  The problem is that a number of files that Wally checked into TFS are missing from my machine.  I can see in the "Source control Explorer" that Wally checked in at least one new file.  When I right mouse click on the Acord project and click "Get Latest", I still don't get Wally's new file.  This is a problem because I've added some new files of my own, so I can't just take Wally's version of the project file.

What can I do to make the project file include the file additions from both Wally's code (that is checked in) and my code (which is only saved in a Shelfset)?

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Did you try to "get latest version" of the whole project?

Comment: Yes, I did try doing "get latest version" on the whole project

Comment: What is this "Visual Studio Merge Tool"? Exactly what commands did you issue?

Comment: Are you selecting the project file?  Make sure you're selecting the *top level folder* that contains everything you're trying to get.  Try doing this in Source Control Explorer, not in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Get the lastest version of the project file, and you will get the opportunity to merge the files (automatically or manually) as you have both made changes to it.

The project file is XML, so you should fairly easilty see what most of it means, and you really only need to understand the part that is the files in the project, so there isn't really any problem if you need to merge them manually.

Comment: I right mouse click on the (checked out) project file and click "Get Latest Version".  I see a progress dialog flash on the screen and then nothing... no opportunity to merge.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: Are you sure that your collegue actually checked in the project, and not only the edited files?

Comment: Yes, As I mentioned in my question, I can see the new files in "Source Control Explorer", so I know that they are there.

Comment: Seeing new files, simply means he added files to the file system. It doesn't mean they were added properly to the project. If you look at history on the project file you could see if he made changes, and from there you should be able to compare it to your current file.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: The fact that you can see the files in the Source Control Explorer doesn't indicate that the project file has been checked in. The files are probably donwloaded to your machine already, but they are not visible as long as they are not in the projecct. You can enable the "Show All Files" option in the Solution Explorer to see all files in the project folder instead of the files in the project. The files have to be part of the project to be compiled though, so you need the changes to the project file, or include the files in your project.